# How to check (and kill) javascript-scroll when bottom of webpage is reached

Tags: javascript, scroll

I've been working in Python for a couple of years and have recently started looking into Javascript (not jQuery or dependencies, just plain Javascript) for some browser automation tasks.

Scrolling sites with lazy load (like a Facebook-page, a Twitter-page or heck even the Wallmart site) in Python is straightforward using fx Selenium.

In Python a rough 'n' dirty solution could be a height-check and break out of a while-loop if the height stops increasing. Like so:

```
check_height = driver.execute_script("return document.body.scrollHeight;") 
while True:
    browser.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")
    time.sleep(2)
    height = driver.execute_script("return document.body.scrollHeight;") 
    if height == check_height: 
        break 
    check_height = height
```

So now I'm trying to accomplish the same thing in Javascript using the Chrome-console. So far a working code looks like this:

```
var scrollToBottom = function() {
    window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);
    }
var sleep = 1000;
var kill_ID = setInterval(scrollToBottom, sleep);
```

The setInterval initiates a loop that goes on forever - with a second of sleep time between each call to scrollToBottom. And I can then - manually - kill it when no more content is loaded by issuing:

```
window.clearInterval(kill_ID);
```

This is obviously not the best way to go about this. So there has to be a better way of accomplishing the task without having to manually kill the scrolling-process.

But the Python logic doesn't seem to work for me in Javascript. Anyone that will give me a couple of pointers as to how to accomplish this - I assume - basic task? Thanks in advance.

**Update:**
As there apparently are no easy fixes for this one, I went with a low tech solution and added an eventListener, that kills the scrolling when I click the mouse (trigger the clearInterval).

So an extra code snippet for this to work - fx as a bookmarklet - would just need to be:

```
window.addEventListener('click', function kill(){window.clearInterval(kill_ID)})
```

Thanks for the helpfull comments, everyone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your approach is correct and I think (and I may be wrong) it is as good as you can if you don't want to use `async/await` approaches.

With `async/await` you can define a loop, like this:

```
async function toTheBottom() {
  while (check if height has changed) {
    window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);
    await sleep(1000);
  }
}
```

Where sleep might be defined as:

```
function sleep(ms) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    setTimeout(resolve, ms);
  });
}
```

Compatibility: https://caniuse.com/#feat=async-functions

Comment: Thanks. This is clean and easy to implement (after I took some async/await-tutorials).

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your problem, you are wanting to do *something* when the window scrolls, and then based on that do *something* else. You should be able to do this via `eventListeners`:

```
window.addEventListener('scroll', event => {
  // Do your checks to see if you need to
  // do your work or not
  if (doWork()) {
    doSomethingElse()
  }
})
```

[Here is a jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/s6Lp3ju5/) of an example that I think does what you are asking

If you wanted to add a dependency, this would become a little easier to do:

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/rxjs/5.5.2/Rx.js"></script>
<script>
  const { Observable } = Rx

  const scrollStream = Observable.fromEvent(window, 'scroll')

  const isTheScrollICareAboutSubscription = scrollStream
    .filter(e => {
      // return true or false if this is
      // an event we care about
      return doWork(e)
    })
    .subscribe(doSomethingElse)
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks, Tim. I'm sorry if my problem is unclear. To the bone: I want to scroll until there's no more content to load. When this happens, I want to kill the scroll. How do I go about that in the first example you give? Thanks.

Comment: I am confused about what you mean by `kill the scroll`. If you don't load any more content, the user cannot scroll down past the bottom of the page so in effect, it `kills the scroll`.

Comment: It seems you're wrong. The code I posted will loop forever. As an effect if you try to scroll to the top (or just a bit up) - after a second you're sent back to the bottom. I guess that's why the setInterval-function needs to have a clearInterval-counterpart...

Comment: Right, your code above won't work without the clearInterval. I am saying if you instead only `doSomethingElse`, as in `load data and expand the page height` if `doWork` returns truthy, then it would `kill the scroll` without needing to clear the interval. Your `doWork` could be `is a down scroll && have more data`

Comment: Thanks, Tim. Since I'm a JS newbie, perhaps you could point me in the right direction as to defining the function you label "is a down scroll && have more data"? Thanks in advance.

Comment: @jlaur I have added a jsfiddle link to the answer. Let me know if you have any further questions.